# Pronoms relatifs dont - où

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

1. Elodie est très fière de la ville où elle est née.
2. Elodie est très fière de la ville dont elle est née.

I know the first phrase is correct. But is the second? 'Elle est fière DE' so I would say it is correct, agree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> {Your phrasing}: Elodie est très fière de la ville **dont** elle est née.

... is not correct. This "dont" has nothing to do with the part "fière de"; it actually serves to connect "née" and "la ville":

> elle est née **de** la ville

"Dont" is the replacement word for "de", but the thing is that you cannot say "née de la ville"; the correct phrasing is "née **dans** la ville". The right connector for the preposition "dans" is "dans laquelle", not "dont":

> {Correct}: Elodie est très fière de la ville **dans laquelle** {or preferably: **où**} elle est née.

By the way, if you'd like "dont" to refer to "de" in "fière de", you can say for instance:

> S'il y a bien une chose **dont** je suis **fière**, c'est **de** ...